# Making text display on top of an image HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Im struggling to get the text in the div footertext to display on top of the image. Im also trying to get it so that the copyrighttext goes to the right corner and the footernavmenu goes to the left corner.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footerimage">
    <img src="images/footer-waves.jpg" width="980" height="140" alt="waves" />
  </div><!-- footer image --> 
  <div id="footertext"> 
    <div id="footernavmenu">
      <ul id="list-footer-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="kayaking-di">kayaking Disciplines</a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Useful links</a></li>
      </ul><!-- ul end list-footer-nav -->
    </div><!-- div end footernavmenu -->
    <div id="copyright">
      <div class="copyrigttext">
        Copyright © 2013 Elliott Davidson, All Rights Reserved.
      </div><!-- end div copyrighttext -->
    </div><!-- end div copyright -->
  </div><!-- end div footertext -->            
</div><!-- end of footer -->
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
    #footer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:175px;
    width:980;
}

#footertext {
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:auto;
}

#footerimage {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:980px;
    height:140px;
}

#footernavmenu {
    width : 480px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul#list-footer-nav {
    list-style : none;
    padding-right : 3px;
    width:auto;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li {
    display : inline;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a {
    text-decoration : none;
    width:auto;
    float : left;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:hover {

}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:active {

}

#copyright {
    width:480px;
    height:auto;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
}

.copyrighttext {

}
```

Comment: Why not set the image as a background-image?

Comment: Why not change the order in html? http://jsfiddle.net/EvDXR/1/

Comment: @loop_duplicate would that be in the HTML or CSS?

Comment: @Danko would this mean wrapping the text and an image in the same div?

Comment: nop just change the order the full div for image at the bottom after the foorter text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more practical solution, you just have to shift the **#footer-text** container and its children within the **#footerimage** container, after the `<img>` tag.

After that you assign a position relative to the footer-text, and then position absolute to the footerimage, and a few other things.  [Please look at my fiddle to experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/BsvDD/1/) with my solution.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footerimage">
    <img src="images/footer-waves.jpg" width="980" height="140" alt="waves" />
      <div id="footertext"> 
        <div id="footernavmenu">
          <ul id="list-footer-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="kayaking-di">kayaking Disciplines</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Useful links</a></li>
          </ul><!-- ul end list-footer-nav -->
        </div><!-- div end footernavmenu -->
        <div id="copyright">
          <div class="copyrigttext">
            Copyright © 2013 Elliott Davidson, All Rights Reserved.
          </div><!-- end div copyrighttext -->
        </div><!-- end div copyright -->
      </div><!-- end div footertext -->          
  </div><!-- footer image --> 
</div><!-- end of footer -->
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
#footer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:175px;
    width:980;
}

#footertext {
    position:absolute;
    width:980px;
    height:auto;
    bottom: 0
}

#footerimage {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:980px;
    height:140px;
    position: relative;
}

#footernavmenu {
    width : 480px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul#list-footer-nav {
    list-style : none;
    padding-right : 3px;
    width:auto;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li {
    display : inline;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a {
    text-decoration : none;
    width:auto;
    float : left;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:hover {

}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:active {

}

#copyright {
    width:480px;
    height:auto;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: right;
}

.copyrighttext {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
    <div id="footertext"> 

        <div id="footernavmenu">

            <ul id="list-footer-nav">

                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>

                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

                <li><a href="kayaking-di">kayaking Disciplines</a></li>

                <li><a href="links.html">Useful links</a></li>

            </ul><!-- ul end list-footer-nav -->

        </div><!-- div end footernavmenu -->

        <div id="copyright">

            <div class="copyrigttext">

                Copyright © 2013 Elliott Davidson, All Rights Reserved.

            </div><!-- end div copyrighttext -->

        </div><!-- end div copyright -->

    </div><!-- end div footertext -->
```

CSS:

```
#footertext {
    background: url('images/footer-waves.jpg') fixed top left no-repeat;
    width: 980px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

To make the copyright go to the right and footernavmenu go to the left:

```
#copyright {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top; // or bottom if you want bottom corner
}

#footernavmenu {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top; // or bottom if you want bottom corner
}
```

Comment: for some reason the image isnt being displayed using your code?

Comment: The url in the css is the path relative to your stylesheet. You may need to adjust the path if the image is not in the images folder relative to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a background-image on the #footertext element:

```
#footertext {
  background-image: url('images/footer-waves.jpg');
}
```

Comment: @loop-duplicate for some reason the image isn't being displayed

Comment: Add Width & height to the background image

Comment: Make sure your image path is correct and relative to your stylesheet (help can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)).

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
 .ParentDivclassThatContainsFooterimageandFootertext{
    position:relative;
  }

#footerimage{
  position:relative;
}

#footertext {
   position:absolute;
    width:980px;
    top: whateversuits;
    left: whateversuits;
   height:auto;
}

  .copyright {
     float: right;
      width:50%; // adjust according to what you want.
    vertical-align: top; // or bottom if you want bottom corner
  }


 .footernavmenu {
   float: left;
    vertical-align: top; // or bottom if you want bottom corner
    width: 50%;  adjust according to what you want.
 }
```